# Dynamic class generation with attributes

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am trying to generate a dynamic class with

```
dynamic_name = 'Person'
Object.const_set(dynamic_name, Class.new {def init(attrs); end})
```

I would like to generate attributes for this class. I tried to do it like this:

```
Person.class.module_eval { attr_accessor :name}
```

But is it possible to put this directly into the `init` method? I would also need to set constraints for the attribute, e.g. the attribute name as above should be of `size > 0` and be allowed to contain characters of the regex `/^[A-Z]/`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I have to create the class dynamically with a dynamic name and also the attributes have dynamic names and types! Is this not the way to accomplish that?

Comment: What is `size`? What is `name`?

Comment: Your last fragment of code is invalid regardless of `size` and `name`.

Comment: This is no code but just an explanation of a constraint

Comment: This sounds like a [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_accessor :name` is nothing but the DSL aka syntactic sugar to define plain accessors for `name` and `name=` methods. It may not have any constraints. To define constraints one should go with explicit setter definition:

```
attr_reader :name
def name= neu
  raise ArgumentError.new("Name must be not empty") if neu.empty?
  # additional constraints
  @name = neu
end
```

The different unrelated to above question is:

> is it possible to put this directly into the `init` method?

While I still do not get what all these woodoo dance for, it is possible:

```
def init *args
  # native init stuff
  self.class.define_method :name do
    @name
  end unless self.class.method_defined? :name
  self.class.define_method :name= do |neu|
    raise ArgumentError.new("Name must be not empty") if neu.empty?
    # additional constraints
    @name = neu
  end unless self.class.method_defined? :name=
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I use the code block below I get the error `test.rb:12:in 'init': private method 'define_method' called for Person:Class (NoMethodError)
 from test.rb:36:in '<main>'
`

Comment: Oh, yes. It is private. Change `self.class.define_method(:name)` to `self.class.send(:define_method, :name)`.

Comment: which one? all `define_method` calls?

Comment: Ok got it, put how do I access the `name` attribute then, when I do it like this `test = Person.new.init 'xxx' puts test.name` I get the error `undefined method `name' for :name:Symbol (NoMethodError)`